# How do I save this and load all of the values from local storage? When I save it, it only saves once?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I stored the Value for the star rating and songs I have but when I load it the previous saved value disappears and the new one pops up instead. I want it all to load locally from storage.
I am using @react-native-async-storage/async-storage and react native with expo and this is an android app.

```
  onLoad = async () => {
    try {
      const star = await AsyncStorage.getItem(keys.starKey);
      const song = await AsyncStorage.getItem(keys.songKey);
      const storedValue = star + song;
      this.setState({ storedValue });
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'There was an error while loading the data');
    }
  }

  onSave = async () => {
    const { starValue, songValue } = this.state;

    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(keys.starKey, starValue);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(keys.songKey, songValue);

      Alert.alert('Saved', 'Successfully saved on device');
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'There was an error while saving the data');
    }
  }
```

my render

```
 <Text style={styles.preview}>{storedValue}</Text>
        <View>
          <Picker label='Star Rating' selectedValue={this.state.starValue} onChangeValue={this.onChange} value = {starValue}
            onValueChange={itemValue => this.setState({ starValue: itemValue })}
            style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}>
            <Picker.Item label='Star Rating' value='' />
            <Picker.Item label='1' value='* ' />
            <Picker.Item label='2' value='** ' />
            <Picker.Item label='3' value='*** ' />
            <Picker.Item label='4' value='**** ' />
            <Picker.Item label='5' value='***** ' />
          </Picker>
          <Picker label='Song Selection' selectedValue={this.state.songValue}
            onValueChange={itemValue => this.setState({ songValue: itemValue })}
            style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}>
            <Picker.Item label='Song Title' value='' />
            <Picker.Item label='People Watching' value='People Watching ' />
            <Picker.Item label='Hunted By A Freak' value='Hunted By a Freak ' />
            <Picker.Item label='Nervous Tic..' value='Nervous Tic ...' />
          </Picker>
        </View>
```

Comment: I think your issue is that you are calling `onLoad` in the render function, which overwrite the state with whatever's in local storage on every render. If you call it in [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) then it will only set state to the local storage value when the component renders for the first time

Comment: Also you may want to create a function for setting `songValue` and `starValue` that boths setState and save the new value to local storage